# Unknown directive .altmacro error happens when using android-ndk standalone toolchain

Tags: c, android-ndk, llvm-clang, toolchain, ndk-build

I am using NDK standalone toolchain to build a dynamic library(.so) on Mac OS.

I just migrate the C language compiler from GCC to clang.When using GCC the processes are all OK and so file is generated successfully. But when using clang,some errors happen when issue ./configure.The errors are as follows.

The picture error logs:

[image: configure errors]

The text error logs,it is the same with the above picture error logs:

```
check_as
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
    1   .altmacro
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
arm-linux-androideabi-clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -I$(SRC_PATH)/compat/float -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.DIksqWpw.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-psabi' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
1 warning generated.
/var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S:1:1: error: unknown directive
.altmacro
^
check_gas using 'arm-linux-androideabi-clang' as AS
check_as
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
    1   .macro m n, y:vararg=0
    2   \n: .int \y
    3   .endm
    4   m x
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
arm-linux-androideabi-clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -I$(SRC_PATH)/compat/float -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.DIksqWpw.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-psabi' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
1 warning generated.
check_as
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
    1   .altmacro
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
arm-linux-androideabi-clang -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -I$(SRC_PATH)/compat/float -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.DIksqWpw.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-psabi' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
1 warning generated.
/var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.t5WIvSJ0.S:1:1: error: unknown directive
.altmacro
^
GNU assembler not found, install/update gas-preprocessor
```

The toolchain configurations in the configure file:

```
  # toolchain
  ar_default="ar"
  cc_default="clang"
  cxx_default="clang++"
  host_cc_default="clang"
  cp_f="cp -f"
  doxygen_default="doxygen"
  install="install"
  ln_s_default="ln -s -f"
  nm_default="nm -g"
  objformat="elf"
  pkg_config_default=pkg-config
  ranlib_default="ranlib"
  strip_default="strip"
  version_script='--version-script'
  yasmexe_default="yasm"
  windres_default="windres"
```

The NDK version is r14b,and the clang version:

```
  Android clang version 3.8.275480  (based on LLVM 3.8.275480)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
  Thread model: posix
```

I know that the error is not caused by the "gas-preprocessor",because GCC compiler also has this problem.The GCC logs with no errors:

```
check_cc
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.51pLIKDT.c
    1   unsigned int endian = 'B' << 24 | 'I' << 16 | 'G' << 8 | 'E';
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.51pLIKDT.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.bcyz1Buv.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.51pLIKDT.c
gas-preprocessor.pl -arch arm -as-type gas -- arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v
./configure: line 883: gas-preprocessor.pl: command not found
check_gas using 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' as AS
check_as
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
    1   .macro m n, y:vararg=0
    2   \n: .int \y
    3   .endm
    4   m x
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.bcyz1Buv.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
check_as
BEGIN /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
    1   .altmacro
END /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Dstrtod=avpriv_strtod -DPIC -O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/Users/zexu/github/ijkplayer/android/contrib/build/openssl-armv7a/output/include -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a8 -fPIC -c -o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.bcyz1Buv.o /var/folders/k6/bsgr75lj6j99fl0q8ygrr7840000gn/T//ffconf.QeTKRayl.S
```

Anyone can give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues with assembler when switching from GCC to Clang are usually fixed with `-fno-integrated-as`. Clang has a built in assembler that it uses for assembling generating code that is not 100% compatible with GNU's assembler. If you have any inline assembly, you will either need to update that assembly to be compatible with LLVM's assembler or pass `-fno-integrated-as` to instruct Clang to use GNU as instead.